# Padding of div in another div affects other elements

Tags: css, html, web, padding

Hello I'm trying to create a navigation bar which is made up of several div containers in one big navigation div.

I'm not sure if my approach is right but I tried to do it like this:

```
<div id="navigation">

    <div class="innen">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img class= "logo" src="logo.png" title="Logo"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="bar">
        <!-- Navigation Items are in here --!>
        </div>

        <div id="gamecard">
        <!-- Another right floated Element !-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="unten">
        <p>You are here: <a href="index.html">Main</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to push down the bar div to meet the height of the image by using top padding:

```
#bar{
padding-top: 80px;
}
```

But now it moves the down gamecard container too. How can I prevent this from happening?

I also added a jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cv4p2/

Comment: #bar {
        position: relative;
        top: 80px;
    }

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients you don't need _that_ many vendor prefixes for gradients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using position:absolute

```
<div id="bar" style="position:absolute; padding: 80px 0 0 0">
</div>
```

Comment: It works but it destroys the float. The Menubar is now in the image.Is there a way to avoid it? @Eugene-Xa approach works, but what is better?

Comment: you need to change the padding, try changing the [top] [right] [bottom] [left] to the position you need. Try like this padding: 80px 0 100px 0

Comment: Ok already played with it and it works but why does it work with `{ position: relative; top: 80px; }`?

Comment: If it works, then you can use that. if you want some info try look at this link http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 1):

Padding is intended to add a cushion inside the container in which you implement it. It appears that you would benefit from using margin. You should replace "padding-top: 80px;" with "margin-top: 80px;" and you would achieve the desired effect.