# padding in one div affects other divs

Tags: html, css

I have three `inline-block` divs like this:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">div1</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; padding-top:5px">div2</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">div3</div>
```

I added a padding to the second div to display it a little lower, but this makes others divs to go down as well. How to make only the second div to display lower?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mY6hP/

The same thing was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226301/padding-of-div-in-another-div-affects-other-elements), but the accepted answer suggests using `absolute` positioning, which i would not like to do.

Comment: you can use `position:relative; top:5px;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the alignment on the other divs so they allign themselves at the top (via `vertical-align:top;`):

```
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">div1</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; padding-top:5px">div2</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">div3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try float:left instead of inline-block display:

```
<div style="float:left">div1</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-top:5px">div2</div>
<div>div3</div>
```